# Is there any way to get the guild object a command is run it?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want my bot to be run in different guilds, and sometimes, I need a guild object to get the different members of the guilds. I've seen some answers that uses **bot.guilds** to get *all* the guilds the bot is in, but how do I get it to output a guild object that a command was run in?

Here is my code so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description='- shows this message', intents=intents)
---- snip ----
@bot.command()
async def get_guild(ctx):
    pass

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ctx` being passed to the command is the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context).  It has an attribute `ctx.guild`, which will be the `discord.Guild` object representing the guild the command was called in (or `None` if it was called in a private channel)